# Thousand separator in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012, ssrs-expression

I have a column in SSRS report which should be shown using thousand separator. I have already tried using text box properties thousand separator check box and it doesn't work.

The column contains decimal values like 10036356.51, -12345.75, etc.

What should be done to display this numbers using thousand separator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thousand separator does not work for Character type datatype like CHAR/VARCHAR.

Cast your column value to DECIMAL OR NUMERIC and TRY.